# removing background color of rows that have nothing in column a

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

[image]The script adds cell background color in non blank cells in a row based on a specified value in column "T" only if column "A" is not blank. problem i'm having is the script is not checking column "A" and then removing background color to the row if there is no value in column "A". I'm looking to see if someone can tell me where i'm going wrong, At the bottom of the script is where I have it checking column "A" and then setting background to 'none'. Is there anyway to optimize this script?, it takes a while to run.

```html
function colors() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet_name = ['Current Sales','Pending Orders', 'Subcontract Orders', 'Partial Shipped', 'Quotes', 'Archived Sales']; 
  for (s=0; s<sheet_name.length; s++) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheet_name[s]);
    var range = sheet.getDataRange()
    var values = range.getValues();
            
     for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
     for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
     if (values[i][j] !== "" && values[i][19] == "Complete") {
        range.getCell(i + 1, j + 1).setBackground("#99FF99");          
        }
   
       if (values[i][j] !== "" && values[i][19] == "Revise") {
        range.getCell(i + 1, j + 1).setBackground("#FA5959");
       }
 
       if (values[i][j] !== "" && values[i][19] == "Pending Next Step") {
        range.getCell(i + 1, j + 1).setBackground("#FFFF33");
       }
 
       if (values[i][j] !== "" && values[i][19] == "Quoted") {
        range.getCell(i + 1, j + 1).setBackground("#FFCCCC");
       }

       if (values[i][j] !== "" && values[i][19] == "Awaiting Vendor Response") {
        range.getCell(i + 1, j + 1).setBackground("#FFCC99");
       }

       if (values[i][j] !== "" && values[i][19] == "Awaiting Customer Response") {
        range.getCell(i + 1, j + 1).setBackground("#FF9999");
       }

       if (values[i][j] !== "" && values[i][19] == "Parts On Order") {
        range.getCell(i + 1, j + 1).setBackground("#FF6666");
       }
       
       if (values[i][j] !== "" && values[i][19] == "Shipped Partial Order") {
        range.getCell(i + 1, j + 1).setBackground("#FFB266");
       }
       
       if (values[i][j] !== "" && values[i][19] == "Awaiting SubContract Parts Work") {
        range.getCell(i + 1, j + 1).setBackground("#66FFFF");
       }
       
       if (values[i][j] !== "" && values[i][19] == "Picking List Printed") {
        range.getCell(i + 1, j + 1).setBackground("#FF9333");
       }
       
       if (values[i][j] !== "" && values[i][19] == "Waiting on BOL / Charges") {
        range.getCell(i + 1, j + 1).setBackground("#3399FF");
       }
       
       if (values[i][j] !== "" && values[i][19] == "Quote Sold") {
        range.getCell(i + 1, j + 1).setBackground("#FF66B2");
       }
       
       if (values[i][j] !== "" && values[i][19] == "Awaiting Vendor Confirmation") {
        range.getCell(i + 1, j + 1).setBackground("#CC99FF");
       }
       
       if (values[i][j] !== "" && values[i][19] == "Ready To Ship") {
        range.getCell(i + 1, j + 1).setBackground("#FFE5CC");
       }

       if (values [i][j] == "" && values[i][0] == "") {
         range.getCell(i + 1, j + 1).setBackground('none');
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

```html
function colors() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet_name = ['Current Sales','Pending Orders', 'Subcontract Orders', 'Partial Shipped', 'Quotes', 'Archived Sales']; 
  for (s=0; s<sheet_name.length; s++) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheet_name[s]);
    var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getMaxRows(),sheet.getMaxColumns());
    var values = range.getValues();
    var cIndex;
    var TArr = ['Complete','Revise','Pending Next Step','Quoted','Awaiting Vendor Response','Awaiting Customer Response','Parts On Order','Shipped Partial Order','Awaiting SubContract Parts Work','Picking List Printed','Waiting on BOL / Charges','Quote Sold','Awaiting Vendor Confirmation','Ready To Ship'];
    var CArr = ['#99FF99','#FA5959','#FFFF33','#FFCCCC','#FFCC99','#FF9999','#FF6666','#FFB266','#66FFFF','#FF9333','#3399FF','#FF66B2','#CC99FF','#FFE5CC']
            
     for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  if (values[i][0] !== "") {  // only if A is not empty
    for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
      if (values[i][j] !== "") {
        cIndex = TArr.indexOf(values[i][19]);
        if (cIndex != -1) {
          range.getCell(i + 1, j + 1).setBackground(CArr[cIndex]);
        }
      }
    } 
  }
}
}
}
```

Comment: There is a space between values and [i][j] in the last if statement.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array with the values of T (TArr) and another one with the corresponding colors (CArr) in the same order, you could set the color like that: find index of T value in TArr and set the color to CArr[index], if A is not empty, otherwise to 'none'.

Cell T needs to be checked only ones per row to find the corresponding color.

```
var cIndex;
var cColor;
var TArr = ['Complete', 'Revise', ...];
var CArr = ['#99FF99', 'FA5959', ...];

for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  // find index of status (T) in TArr
  cIndex = TArr.indexOf(values[i][19]);
  // find the corresponding color in CArr
  cColor = ((cIndex != -1) && (cIndex < CArr.length)) ? CArr[cIndex] : 'none';
  for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
    if (values[i][0] !== "") {  // if A is not empty
      if (values[i][j] !== "") { // if cell is not empty, set color        
        range.getCell(i + 1, j + 1).setBackground(cColor);
      }
    } else { // A is empty
      range.getCell(i + 1, j + 1).setBackground('none');
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: what about to check if no values and then remove background?

Comment: the else portion, I added in and is not removing background colors of an empty row.

Comment: See the update please. There is more to improve. I just don't know exactly, what kind of data and so on. You could make an array for the values in [i][19] and the corresponding color and then just set the color in the loop instead of checking that value again and again.

Comment: I've been trying to make an array for the values in [i][19] but have not been able to figure out how to do so

Comment: I don't get yet exactly, what you try to do there. If [i][0] is empty, all the cells in the row shouldn't have a background-color? Don't you have an image of what you try to achieve?

Comment: I added a picture, the script sets the background color based on the status selected in column T, it then puts a background color to non blank cells within the row, if a row has nothing in column "A" then I want it to remove background color to any cell within the row.

Comment: Is there a default background-color or could we just say: the bg needs to be set only, if A is not empty?

Comment: the background only needs to be set if A is not empty, correct.

Comment: So the j-loop needs to run only if A is not empty, if I see that right.

Comment: I used your latest revision and the bg colors work great, I inserted my code using this back at the top. I am still unable to remove background on empty rows where column "A" is empty.

Comment: I don't understand in what case you need to remove bg colors since they shouldn't be set in the first place if A is empty - whether or not the whole row is empty.

Comment: I apologize I probably left this out, this script is part of a bigger onEdit script function that moves rows to another sheet tab based on the selection of status in "T", when this happens the sheet the row is moved from is left with bg color. My goal was to make this color script apply bg colors and then test the sheets for empty rows and remove bg colors.

Comment: In that case we need the j-loop also for rows with empty A, so we can remove the cell color if necessary. Please see the update and please don't foget to add the var cColor. I moved the check for the color to the i-loop since it needs to be done only ones per row.

Comment: I revised the code, same results. I'm attaching an editable link to the sheet if you would like to see. Script file Set Boarders.gs > function colors() [link to sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tgJrFo0rHmDc7SK7DUdgSvD4H8Q6znDCTooiJ8lCa-s/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Do you use getRange() or getDataRange()? Is it always the last row where the bg is not removed?

Comment: for function colors() I was using getDataRange() becuase the function getRange(A2:V1000) was adding a 1000 rows. I understand that function getDataRange() was not picking up the last row with bg because there was no longer a border around it? at least thats my understanding.

Comment: You can [choose how many rows](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns) you want getRange() to return and you can find the position of the last row containing data with [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188074/discussion-between-shane-and-olafant).

Answer (score 0):

I had assistance with fixing my code. here is the working script that greatly decreased execution time. @Olafant, your assistance was greatly appreciated.

```html
function SetFormatting() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('Apply Borders/Colors')
  .addItem('Set Borders','bordersNoArg')
  .addSeparator()
  .addSubMenu(SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Apply Colors')
              .addItem('Apply Colors', 'colorsNoArg'))              
  .addToUi();
}

function borders(sheet_name) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  for (s=0; s<sheet_name.length; s++) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheet_name[s]);    
    var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn());
    var values = range.getValues();
    var offsetRow = range.getRowIndex();
                  
    range.setBorder(false, false, false, false, false, false);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (values[i][0]) { // Only for non-empty A column cells
        sheet.getRange("A" + (i + offsetRow) + ":V" + (i + offsetRow)).setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false, "black",SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DOUBLE);
        for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
          if (values[i][j] !== "") {
            range.getCell(i + 1, j + 1).setBorder(null,true,null,true,true,true);
          }
        }
      } 
    }
  }    
}

function bordersNoArg(){
  var sheet_name = ['Current Sales','Pending Orders', 'Subcontract Orders', 'Partial Shipped', 'Quotes', 'Archived Sales'];
  borders(sheet_name)
}

function colors(sheet_name) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  for (s=0; s<sheet_name.length; s++) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheet_name[s]);
    var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn());
    var values = range.getValues();
    var cIndex;
    var TArr = ['Complete','Revise','Pending Next Step','Quoted','Awaiting Vendor Response','Awaiting Customer Response','Parts On Order','Shipped Partial Order','Awaiting SubContract Parts Work','Picking List Printed','Waiting on BOL / Charges','Quote Sold','Awaiting Vendor Confirmation','Ready To Ship'];
    var CArr = ['#99ff99','#fa5959','#ffff33','#ffcccc','#ffcc99','#ff9999','#ff6666','#ffb266','#66ffff','#ff9333','#3399ff','#ff66b2','#cc99ff','#ffe5cc']
    var exisBackGrounds = range.getBackgrounds();
    
    //Set Empty rows background to null
    var emptyRng = sheet.getRange((sheet.getLastRow() + 2),1,sheet.getMaxRows(),sheet.getMaxColumns());
    emptyRng.setBackground(null);
    
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (values[i][0] !== "") { // only if A is not empty
        for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
          if (values[i][j] !== "") {
            cIndex = TArr.indexOf(values[i][19]);
            if (cIndex != -1) {
              if(exisBackGrounds[i][j] != CArr[cIndex]){
                range.getCell(parseInt(i) + 1, parseInt(j) + 1).setBackground(CArr[cIndex]);
              }
            }
          }else{
            if(exisBackGrounds[i][j] != '#ffffff'){
                range.getCell(parseInt(i) + 1, parseInt(j) + 1).setBackground(null);
              } 
          }
        }
      }else{
        sheet.getRange(parseInt(i) + 2,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).setBackground(null);
      }
    }
  }
}


function colorsNoArg() {
  var sheet_name = ['Current Sales','Pending Orders', 'Subcontract Orders', 'Partial Shipped', 'Quotes', 'Archived Sales'];
  colors(sheet_name);
}
```

Comment: There is only unnecessary stuff added to my code. There is no need to clear the background for all cells not containing data since the range is here properly set as I [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54535746/removing-background-color-of-rows-that-have-nothing-in-column-a/54541765#comment95920714_54541765). Since i and j are never strings it makes no sense to parseInt them but decreases performance. getBackgrounds() and then checking against CArr[cIndex] doesn't increase perfomance at all. To post and accept that doesn't show any appreciation of my efforts to help you.

Comment: @Olafant I removed the accepted answer, would you be able to expand on your code? I was unable to get your coding to work successfully.